# How do I get an imageView and textview to both fill the layout when setting bitmap programmatically?

Tags: android, android-layout

What I want is for `qrcodetext` to fit and display all the text in `qrcode_layout` and have `qrimageView` to fill the rest of `qrcode_layout`? But my layout below has the entire `qrimageView` cover `qrcode_layout`. I tried a bunch of other variations but without success.

Here is what it looks like.

[image]

Here is what I want it to look like.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/qrcodelayout">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/qrimageView"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/qrcodetext"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you post a screenshot how it looks right now and how you want it to show?

Comment: @VivekMishra I've updated the question with some images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following code. Align your textview to bottom and then align your Qrcode Image above text:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">        
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/qrcodetext"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp" />        
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/qrimageView"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_above="@id/qrcodetext"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what i have understand you want is below: Plz check and tell me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/qrcodelayout">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/qrcodetext"
            android:gravity="center"            
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/qrimageView"                
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />

        </LinearLayout>



    </LinearLayout>

    <!--<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>-->

</RelativeLayout>
```